# Frame animation from outside screen and translateto inside screen

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, frame

I'm new to animation with Xamarin Forms, I have a frame that I need to place it outside the screen like this:

[image: outside]

The small frame is outside the device's screen

[image: inside]

The small frame now inside the device screen

My problem is I need to know how I can place the frame like that (outside the screen) from the start, and how to know the width and the height of every device so I can use the TranslateTo() method to translate the frame to the exact same position for every device.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this from your .cs page

- **Application.Current.MainPage.Width**
- **Application.Current.MainPage.Height**

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/?context=xamarin/xamarin-forms) NuGet pakage to achieve this. And there is a useful class `DeviceDisplay` in there that should be helpful for you.

The documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?tabs=android).

Usage example:

```
        // Get Metrics
        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;

        // Orientation (Landscape, Portrait, Square, Unknown)
        var orientation = mainDisplayInfo.Orientation;

        // Rotation (0, 90, 180, 270)
        var rotation = mainDisplayInfo.Rotation;

        // Width (in pixels)
        var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;

        // Height (in pixels)
        var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;

        // Screen density
        var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
```